# lerp z rotation towards mousepointer

Tags: unity, mathematics, rotation, lerp

I am trying to get `transform.rotation.z` to chase the mouse pointer at a rotation speed. But I get a very weird results and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
var mp = Input.mousePosition;
var camZ = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
// Grab the current mouse position on the screen.
// Subtract the cams Z from the mouse Z to get ground plane. 
var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (
                           new Vector3 (mp.x, mp.y, mp.z - camZ));
//Rotates toward the mouse                      
var targetEuler = new Vector3 (0, 0, 
      Mathf.Atan2 ((mousePos.y - transform.position.y), 
                   (mousePos.x - transform.position.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90);
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0,
      Mathf.Lerp (transform.eulerAngles.z, targetEuler.z,
                  Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed));
```

Answer (score 0):

OKi was way off.  This is how i got it to work.

```
                        rotationTarget = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);                      

                    var _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (transform.position - rotationTarget, Vector3.forward);

                    _lookRotation.x = 0.0f;

                    _lookRotation.y = 0.0f;

                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
```